# How to verify Google Analytics Tracking Status for Intranet site?

Tags: google-analytics

So how do we make Google Analytics Verify the Tracking Status for our intranet sites?

I created a new Site/property in Google Analytics, added that tracking code to Intranet site which work fine, I checked using Google Analytics Helper and Debugger.  The tracking is showing up in Real Time report in Google Analytics.

The problem is that Google Analytics Tracking Status is "Tracking Not Installed" which make sense since it can't hit the intranet site.

How would we make Google Analytics Verify the Tracking Status?

I thought of making it point to some legit public site page with that tracking codes but not sure if that works or cause any issue.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it still doesn't do this for me after a couple of weeks.

I found a solution around this.  If you have a place to host an HTML page (a website), simply create an HTML page with the verification codes, put the page up where it can be access over the internet.  Then point the Google analytics Default website URL to that page.  Then give it a day or two (probably a couple hours) and it should be verified.

Answer (score 0):

Your intranet must be able to reach either http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js or https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js, and it needs to be of this format http://intranet.domain.com. More information can be found here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009688?hl=en. The not tracking status is typical if you just installed analytics on your site and you need to wait at least 24 hours for the status to update.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this @nyuen.  I followed all the requirements above.  I see the analytics are send when I use Google Analytics debugger and also see it in real time report.  So it is definitely can get to the analytics.js.

It has been 3 days now and the status is still "Tracking not installed."

This is troublesome.

Comment: You are able to see it in the RT reports? That's a good sign. Do you see the data in your standard reports then?

Comment: I can see the RT reports but I can't see the data in Standard report.